# Imbalanced Image Dataset using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, training-data

I am trying to balance my image dataset using `WeightedRandomSampler` but after loading data using `Dataloader`, I am unable to split the dataset to train and test. Could anyone please guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You should split your `Dataset` (e.g., using [`data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split)) not your `DataLoader`. The split should be agnostic to the way you sample/process your *training* data. Only after you have a training split of the data you can apply [`WeightedRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler) to it.